# Can't understand how the calculation of this recursive program works

Tags: java, recursion

why the base is only getting multiplied by power-1

```
int printnum(int base,int power){
    if(power==0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return printnum(base,power-1)*base;
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing is *"getting multiplied by power-1"*, there is no statement like that in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base` is not multiplied by `power - 1`, it is multiplied by `printnum(base,power-1)`, which is equal to base <sup>power - 1</sup>.

It follows this formula:

base <sup>power</sup> = base <sup>power - 1</sup> * base

Comment: thanks but why cant i do ths  printnum(base,(power-1)*base);

Comment: @SilenceKiills the second argument of the method is the power. What would be the meaning of passing (power - 1)*base to it?

Comment: Hmm i got it now thanks